# How to get resource strings from ASP.NET markup?

Tags: c#, asp.net, resources, globalization, embedded-resource

Hi 
I have an assembly called like X.Common.DLL. There is some resources files for multilanguage app. Let's say it Language.resx Language.en-US.resx....etc....

I have a web application which contains this above dll as reference...

So how can I use this resources file in my web applications markup side?

`Text="<%$ Resources:Class, ResourceKey %>"` is not valid because of "Class" name is in another assembly...

Comment: do you own the source for the DLL? if so, why not just create a thin api in the source - eg expose the strings as public properties? Then you can call into that from your HTML..

Comment: first of all I do not want to touch the web application's code base...And if I do as you said, I have to manage localization thing...But if I can manage to do like that, .NET framework would handle it for me...BTW,thanks a lot for your reply...

Answer (score 3):

You can easily create a wrapper class that does something like this

```
public class ResourceWrapper
{
     private ResourceManager resourceManager;

     public ResourceWrapper()
     {
         resourceManager = new ResourceManager("Namespace.Common", Assembly.Load("x.common"))
     }

     public string String(string resourceKey)
     {
         return ResourceManager.GetString(resourceKey);
     }
 }
```

Finding the correct name for the first param to new ResourceManager(...) can be a bit tricky sometimes. 
To make it easier for yourself you can call like this:

```
Assembly.Load("x.common").GetManifestResourceNames() and check the returned results.
```

If you create a static wrapper, you can make the resource calling code as simple as this:

```
<%= Resource.String("MyResourceKey") %>
```

Answer (score 0):

You should reference the other assembly in web.config to expose its content in web forms. 
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms164642.aspx

Edit : more detailed answer due to comments under :
You should complete the pages/namespaces section of the webconfig like this :

```
<pages>
    <namespaces>
        ...
        <add namespace="My.Fully.Qualified.Namespace"/>
    </namespaces>   
</pages>
```

Of course the assembly which provides the namespaces should also be referenced (project references,  web.config's section)

Then you should be able to write things like "<%= MyResx.MyEntry %>

Comment: You link is how to auto-import namespaces in asp.net pages/controls. What you need is to add the assembly in the compilation section http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/s10awwz0.aspx

Comment: This is exactly why posting answers that just link to another site are not helpful. This answer (or perhaps the first comment) could have answered my question, but since the links are dead, it's useless.

Comment: Agree with you, i've edited my own answer. didn't re-read the whole question but I think it's the expected answer.